# How can I display a select list (dropdown) for a Model property in BackboneJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js

I am trying to build a simple contact editor application in Backbone.js and I have run into a bit of an issue that I don't know how to solve because I'm not familiar with Backbone.js yet.

I have a Model `Contact` and that item has a field `ProductLineID` (each Contact has a Product Line that it is associated with). In displaying the editor for this Contact I would like to display a dropdown list with the possible ProductLine options and have it preset to the current value. How would I do that in Backbone.js?

I know how to do it in knockout.js with data-binding:

```xml
<select id="ProductLineID" name="ProductLineID"
        data-bind="options: productLineOptions, 
        optionsValue: 'ID', 
        optionsText: 'Name', 
        value: ProductLineID, 
        optionsCaption: 'All'">
</select>
```

In this example productLineOptions is a JSON object that is already preloaded on the page.

That would accomplish precisely what I want, but I don't know how to do the equivalent in Backbone.js.

I can provide more code from my actual example, but this seems like it's a bit of a trivial example and does not require specific code.

Comment: Did you achieve it?? How did you manage to show `Default Selected Value` i.e `value:ProductLineID` ??

Answer (score 13):

Something like the following would work if you used the [underscore templates](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template):

```xml
<select id="ProductLineID" name="ProductLineID">
    <option value="">--select a product line--</option>
    <% _(productLineOptions).each(function(pl) { %>
      <option value="<%= pl.ID %>"><%= pl.Name %></option>
    <% }); %>
</select>
```

And then you would just have to make sure that you passed in the `productLineOptions` object into the template's context.

Comment: is there a way to combine this with the built in rendering of a view in backbone?

Comment: Backbone's builtin view rendering doesn't do anything, literally. So you could do something like: (1) put the above into a template (2) in your `render` function call the template with the correct context `render: function() { this.template({ productLineOptions: productLineOptions}); return this; }`

Comment: I got another issue when I added the 'selected' attribute into the template, but it always selected the first one, even if another option  was set selected.

Answer (score 4):

Backbone.js does not do databinding out of the box, like Knockout does.  It leaves that aspect up to the developer to do however they wish.  The basic way is to set up event listeners for changes.

If you do want to do knockout-style databinding, there's a project which may support what you need.

https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding

Comment: I understand that backbone does not provide the same sort of inline data-bind functionality, but is there any suggested way to accomplish the same thing using backbone? I am probably going to give the modelbinding plugin a try, but to me that's not a truly "backbone" way of accomplishing it.